# Databricks Magic Sql - Export Data

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

Is it possible to export the output of a "magic SQL" command cell in Databricks?

I like the fact that one doesn't have to escape the SQL command and it can be easily formatted. But, I cant seem to be able to use the output in other cells. What I would like to do is export the data to a CSV file, but potentially, finish some final manipulation of the dataframe before I write it out.

```
sql = "select * from calendar"
df = sqlContext.sql(sql)
display(df.limit(10))
```

vs (DBricks formatted the following code)

```
%sql
select
  *
from
  calendar
```

but imagine, once you bring in escaped strings, nested joins, etc. Wondering if there is a better way to work with SQL in databricks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is the most obvious one that I didn't think of: create a view!

```
%sql

CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW vwCalendar as
/*
  Comments to make your future self happy!
 */
select
  c.line1,   -- more comments
  c.line2,   -- more comments
  c.zipcode
from
  calendar
where
  c.status <> 'just an example\'s' -- <<imagine escaping this
```

and now you can use the view vwCalendar in subsequent SQL cells just like any other table.

and if you want to use it in a python cell:

```
df = spark.table("vwCalendar")
display(df.limit(3))
```

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-view.html

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html#user-defined-functions---python